# How can I access this property in my dictionary in js?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach

I thought I understood how to loop through a dictionary, but my loop is wrong. I try to access the name of each sub item but my code does not work.
Here is what I did:

```
list = [
      {
        title: 'Groceries',
        items: [
          {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Food',
            cost: 540 ,
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            title: 'Hygiene',
            cost: 235,
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            title: 'Other',
            cost: 20,
          },
        ],
      }];

function calculateCost(){
let total = 0;
Object.keys(list).forEach((k) => { for (i in k.items) { total += i.data; } });
console.log(total);
return total;
}
```

Comment: `list` is an Array. Why are you using `Object.keys(list)`?

Comment: Oh, I am new to js so I thought this was considered a dictionary my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your **list** is an **array** includes **1 object** and this **object** has **two properties** **title** and **items** the **items** here is an **array** of **objects** each one of these **objects** has property **cost** so to calculate the total cost you need to loop through **items** array, here is how you do it:

```js
let list = [
      {
        title: 'Groceries',
        items: [
          {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Food',
            cost: 540 ,
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            title: 'Hygiene',
            cost: 235,
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            title: 'Other',
            cost: 20,
          },
        ],
      }];

function calculateCost(){
let total = 0;
  list[0].items.forEach(el => {
    total += el.cost;
  })
  console.log(total)
  return total;
}

calculateCost();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` is an Array, not an Object.
Instead of Object.keys() use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const calculateCost = (arr) => arr.reduce((tot, ob) =>
  ob.items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.cost, tot), 0);

const list = [
  {
    title: 'Groceries',
    items: [
      {id: 4, title: 'Food', cost: 10},
      {id: 5, title: 'Hygiene', cost: 20},
      {id: 6, title: 'Other', cost: 30}
    ]
  }, {
    title: 'Other',
    items: [
      {id: 8, title: 'Scuba gear', cost: 39}
    ],
  }
];

console.log(calculateCost(list));  // 99
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Roko's and @mmh4all's answers, the following code adds several verification statements to handle cases where a deeply nested property in your data is not what you expect it to be.

```js
const calculateCost = (orders) => {
    let listOfCosts = [];
    // For each 'order' object in the 'orders' array, 
    // add the value of the 'cost' property of each item 
    // in the order to 'listOfCosts' array.
    orders.forEach(order => {
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray
        if (!Array.isArray(order.items)) { return; }
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat
        const orderCostArr = order.items.map(item =>
            isNaN(item.cost) ? 0 : parseFloat(item.cost, 10));
        if (orderCostArr.length === 0) { return; }
        // Concatenate 'orderCostArr' to the 'listOfCosts' array
        //listOfCosts = listOfCosts.concat(orderCostArry);
        // Alternate approach is to use the spread syntax (...) to
        // push the items in the array returned by 'order.items.map()'
        // into the 'listOfCosts' array.
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
        listOfCosts.push(...orderCostArr);
    });
    // Use the 'reduce' method on the 'listOfCosts' array
    // to get the total cost.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
    const totalCost = listOfCosts.reduce(
        (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0);
    return totalCost;
};

const list = [
    {
        title: 'Groceries',
        items: [
            { id: 4, title: 'Food', cost: 10 },
            { id: 3, title: 'Baked goods', cost: 20 },
            { id: 5, title: 'Hygiene', cost: 0 },
            { id: 6, title: 'Other' }
        ]
    }, {
        title: 'Gear',
        items: {},
    }, {
        title: 'Accessories',
        items: [],
    }, {
        title: 'Bags',
    }, {
        title: 'Other',
        items: [
            { id: 10, title: 'Scuba gear', cost: "5" },
            { id: 8, title: 'Scuba gear', cost: "err" },
            { id: 9, title: 'Scuba gear', cost: 59 }
        ],
    }
];

console.log(calculateCost(list));  // 94
```